# Is safe ( documented behaviour? ) to delete the domain of an iterator in execution

Tags: python, iteration, undocumented-behavior

I wanted to know if is safe ( documented behaviour? ) to delete the domain space of an iterator in execution in Python.

Consider the code:

```
import os
import sys

sampleSpace = [ x*x for x in range( 7 ) ]

print sampleSpace

for dx in sampleSpace:

    print str( dx )

    if dx == 1:

        del sampleSpace[ 1 ]
        del sampleSpace[ 3 ]

    elif dx == 25:

        del sampleSpace[ -1 ]

print sampleSpace
```

'sampleSpace' is what I call 'the domain space of an iterator' ( if there is a more appropriate word/phrase, lemme know ).

What I am doing is deleting values from it while the iterator 'dx' is running through it.

Here is what I expect from the code :

```
Iteration versus element being pointed to (*):

0: [*0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36]
1: [0, *1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36] ( delete 2nd and 5th element after this iteration )
2: [0, 4, *9, 25, 36]
3: [0, 4, 9, *25, 36] ( delete -1th element after this iteration )
4: [0, 4, 9, 25*] ( as the iterator points to nothing/end of list, the loop terminates )
```

.. and here is what I get:

```
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36]
0
1
9
25
[0, 4, 9, 25]
```

As you can see - what I expect is what I get - *which* is contrary to the behaviour I have had from other languages in such a scenario.

Hence - I wanted to ask you if there is some rule like "the iterator becomes invalid if you mutate its space during iteration" in Python?

Is it safe ( documented behaviour? ) in Python to do stuff like this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [the Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements):

> It is not safe to modify the sequence
>   being iterated over in the loop (this
>   can only happen for mutable sequence
>   types, such as lists). If you need to
>   modify the list you are iterating over
>   (for example, to duplicate selected
>   items) you must iterate over a copy.
>   The slice notation makes this
>   particularly convenient:
>
> ```
> >>> for x in a[:]: # make a slice copy of the entire list
> ...    if len(x) > 6: a.insert(0, x)
> ...
> >>> a
> ['defenestrate', 'cat', 'window', 'defenestrate']
> ```

Comment: Aha! This is what I was looking for. After reading this piece of text, I would, in my sense of the word, say the operation is *not safe*

Comment: Marking yours as the answer as it directly answered my question. SilentGhost's is more detailed and rich in examples though.

Comment: Because the behaviour is not defined by the Python language, the outcome is free to change between different implementations, or even different versions of the same implementation

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking no, it's not safe and you may get unpredictable behaviour. Iterators aren't required to behave in an specific way under these circumstances.

What's happening in your example is

```
# list is [0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36]

if dx == 1:
    # we're at index 1 when this is true
    del sampleSpace[ 1 ]
    # we've removed the item at index 1, and the iterator will move to the next valid position - still index 1, but in a mutated list. We got lucky in this case
    # the list now contains [0, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36]
    del sampleSpace[ 3 ]   
    # we remove the item at index 3 which is (now) value 16
    # the list now contains [0, 4, 9, 25, 36]
elif dx == 25:

    del sampleSpace[ -1 ]
    # we remove the final item, list now looks like
    # the list now contains [0, 4, 9, 25]
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by safe? Your code happens not to raise any errors, but it is a distinct possibility of course, consider this:

```
>>> a = range(3)
>>> for i in a:
    del a


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#13>", line 2, in <module>
    del a
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
>>> a
[0, 1, 2]
>>> for i in a:
    del a[i+1]


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#27>", line 2, in <module>
    del a[i+1]
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

It is not clear why would you want to do this, but there is no additional rules applicable to iterators. They're acting exactly as any other type would.

Comment: I would need to operate on a list of files in a directory. Now it might happen that my operations, as a side effect, end up operating on  other files besides the one explicitly passed. In that case, I do not want to operate again on the very same files just because they are in the same list. Should I raise this as a separate question if it reads too fuzzy?

Comment: @PoorL: why would you mutate iterator in a first place?

Comment: Here is my situation : Say I find 3 text files in the current directory a,b,c,d. I want to make backups of all text files. Hence I store these filenames into the 'master list' In my function that handles the backup, I realize that b and c are actually copies of a - hence I really do not need to back them up. Instead of adding code to explicitly skip over such files, I would like to delete the entries from the 'master list'. This brings up the scenario that I posted. How else can I handle this without adding explicit checks for skipping entries?

Comment: @PoorL: there are many ways to do this. According to the Zen of Python: "explicit is better than implicit". It might not be such a bad idea to just add simple checks. There is another way, of course, create a class that would represent a file, and do the whole comparison thing through `set`s, I don't think that any advice here would be helpful, without seeing your actual task at hand first.